# How to show only drop-filter but not the source image?

Tags: css, dropshadow

I'm cracking my head for days. I can't figure out how to show only the drop-filter that I assign in CSS to an background image (with alpha), but not show the image itself. The drop-filter's opacity is linked to the alpha of the image. So setting the opacity of the image to 0, also sets the drop-filter's opacity on 0. So that doesn't work. Setting visibility to hide, is also not working.

Comment: provide problem related code and put specific questions.

Comment: What do you mean by ‘drop-filter’? You need to show the code you are using as we can’t tell how you are applying the background.

Comment: #some-div{
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height:100%;
    background: url("some_image_with_alpha_channel.gif");
    filter:  drop-shadow (20px 20px 20px green); 
}